# How to add several buttons and their click events dynamically in c# code behind?

Tags: c#, winforms, code-behind

Hi I want to add several buttons and their click events dynamically to my windows forms application in my code behind where my buttons will execute `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(targetURL);`  how can I acheieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to create the button, set it's properties and event handlers and then add it to the `Controls` collection on the form.

```
var button = new Button();
try
{
    button.Text = "Button 1";
    button.Click += (sender, e) => System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(targetURL);
    //Or if you don't want to use a lambda and would rather have a method;
    //button.Click += MyButton_Click;
    Controls.Add(button);
}
catch
{
    button.Dispose();
    throw;
}

//Only needed when not using a lambda;
void MyButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(targetURL);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add any control you like to the [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls) collection of the form:

```
var targetURL = // ...

try
{
    SuspendLayout();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var button = new Button();
        button.Text = String.Format("Button {0}", i);
        button.Location = new Point(0, i * 25);
        button.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(targetURL);
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
finally
{
    ResumeLayout();
}
```

When adding several controls to a parent control, it is recommended that you call the [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout) method before initializing the controls to be added. After adding the controls to the parent control, call the [`ResumeLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout) method. Doing so will increase the performance of applications with many controls.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your buttons variables.

Add the event handlers

Add them to the form Controls property.

Profit

Answer (score 2):

You could write a user control that contains a textbox "txbURL", a button "btnNavigateToURL" and write the eventhandler of your button, to execute your code (System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(targetURL);)

Once you've done that, it's easy to add your control to your form on runtime, writing some code like this (don't have a c# editor right now, so you may have to verify the code)

```
MyControlClassName userControl = new MyControlClassName(string targetUrl);
userControl.Parent = yourForm;
yourForm.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

that's it.